# Global name 'debug' not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7, activepython

I'm trying to write a script that authenticates to AD. Here's my problem:

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open('output.csv', 'w')
def ad_dict(ldapobj,attr_dict={},recurse=0,auth=1,filter=()):
  if ldapobj.find(',')==-1: ldapobj='cn='+ldapobj+','+Ad.ldap_main_loc
  if auth: #setup authenticated connections
   if debug: print 'auth'
```

When I run it, it gets as far as this and says that "Global name 'debug' is not defined.
I thought that debug was built in here, why wouldn't it be defined?. If it helps, I'm using ActivePython for this script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just define a global variable called debug if you need this functionality? (or use logging.debug() )

Comment: so at the beginning I would just put in `global debug`?

Comment: no, just `debug=True` or `debug=False` as appropriate. `global` is used to modify global variables inside functions.

Comment: So, `debug = True` and then on it goes to the next undefined variable, opends. I thought the site I pulled this from gave me a complete script.

Answer (score 1):

The built-in global constant is called [`__debug__`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html#__debug__) not `debug`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use ActivePython, said that. debug is not a built in regular Python. You can take a look at [python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html), to see all the built ins.